# Java library is overriding log4j.properties

Tags: java, log4j

I have a log4j.properties file:

```
    # Root logger option
    log4j.rootLogger=WARN, stdout, file

    # Redirect log messages to console
    log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
    log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

    # Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
    log4j.appender.file.append=false
    log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.file.File=log/pure-pentaho.log
    log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
    log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
    log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

This works fine until I include the bsf-2.4.0.jar library and then all of my logging stops.

So I am guessing that this library is somehow overriding my logger, how can I get it to resume logging again ?

## Edit

OK, as suggested, I added the path as a command line option and it works:

```
java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:./run/log4j.properties -cp ./lib/*:./run myApp &
```

Comment: Probably you can configure log4j in your code at the main entry point  with [PropertyConfigurator](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there are multiple log4j.properties files in the classpath, and log4j did not pick up yours.

You can rename your file, add a JVM argument to specify your desired file.

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=/home/user/mylog4j.properties
```

To set JVM Arguments on Eclipse, right click on the project > Run as > Run Configurations... > Arguments > VM Arguments

Comment: Thanks so much for helping, but there is only 1 .properties file in the class path, and it works fine until I add the bsf library. Logs are created in the file specified and outputted to the console, but as soon as I add the bsf library everything stops !

Comment: I just checked bsf-2.4.0.jar, it has a log4j.properties inside.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not using eclipse, I am just using a text editor, do I simply add this as a command line option "-Dlog4j.configuration=/home/user/mylog4j.properties"

Comment: Yes, `java [options] classname [args]`